# How to mock generic method in Java with Mockito?

Tags: java, generics, mockito

How can we mock the `IRouteHandlerRegistry`? The error is `Cannot resolve method thenReturn(IHandleRoute<TestRoute>)`

```
public interface RouteDefinition { }

public class TestRoute implements RouteDefinition { }

public interface IHandleRoute<TRoute extends RouteDefinition> {
    Route getHandlerFor(TRoute route);
}

public interface IRouteHandlerRegistry {
    <TRoute extends RouteDefinition> IHandleRoute<TRoute> getHandlerFor(TRoute route);
}

@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void test() {
    // in my test
    RouteDefinition route = new TestRoute(); // TestRoute implements RouteDefinition
    IRouteHandlerRegistry registry = mock(IRouteHandlerRegistry.class);
    IHandleRoute<TestRoute> handler = mock(IHandleRoute.class);

    // Error: Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(IHandleRoute<TestRoute>)'
    when(registry.getHandlerFor(route)).thenReturn(handler);
}
```

Comment: What is `SutFactory`?

Comment: Can you explain what about this doesn't work? What is the error/warning that you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though `TestRoute` is a subtype of `RouteDefinition`, a `IHandleRoute<TestRoute>` is **not** a subtype of `IHandleRoute<RouteDefinition>`.

The `when` method from Mockito returns an object of type `OngoingStubbing<IHandleRoute<RouteDefinition>>`. This is due to the compiler inferring the type parameter `TRoute` from the method

```
<TRoute extends RouteDefinition> IHandleRoute<TRoute> getHandlerFor(TRoute route);
```

to be `RouteDefinition` since the argument passed to `getHandlerFor` is declared of type `RouteDefinition`.

On the other hand, the `thenReturn` method is given an argument of type `IHandleRoute<TestRoute>` whereas it expects an `IHandleRoute<RouteDefinition>`, that is the type argument of the `OngoingStubbing` mentioned earlier. Hence the compiler error.

To solve this, the simplest way is probably to change the declaration type of `route` to be `TestRoute`:

```
TestRoute route = new TestRoute();

IRouteHandlerRegistry registry = mock(IRouteHandlerRegistry.class);
IHandleRoute<TestRoute> handler = mock(IHandleRoute.class);

when(registry.getHandlerFor(route)).thenReturn(handler);
```

Comment: thank you, this helps me with my understanding of java generics as well

Answer (score 5):

If you write like this it will be ok:

```
Mockito.doReturn(handler).when(registry).getHandlerFor(Mockito.any(route.class))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Mockito.when` argument should be a method not a mock.

The correct statement is:
 `when(registry.getHandlerFor (route)).thenReturn(handler)`

Comment: You are correct, sorry I made an edit using my phone and didn't edit it correctly... this wasn't my issue though.